# Inline error/exception handling in python

Tags: python, list, inline, lambda

So, I have 3 lists as follows:

```
list_1 = ['a','b','c'] 
list_2 = ['b','c']
list_3 = [5,4]
```

I am looking to generate a fourth list of values from list_2 & list_3 that will map to list_1. list_2 and list_3 are independent of list_1 but are subsets of list_1 and do map to each other. i.e list_2 and list_3 is missing item 'a' and corresponding values.

I want to handle the missing values and assign some value i.e 0 or empty string. I would like to do this with an inline function. so far, I have tried the following but it fails. What am I doing wrong?

```
list_4 =[lambda i:list_3[list_2.index(list_1[i])] except "" for i in range(len(list_1))]
```

My final result should look like this:

```
list_4=[0,5,4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you check for the presence of the value, instead of relying on exception handling?

```
list_4 = [(list_3[list_2.index(item)] if item in list_2 else 0) for index,item in enumerate(list_1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient way to do what you want:

```
dict_2_to_3 = dict(zip(list_2, list_3))
list_4 = [dict_2_to_3.get(i, 0) for i in list_1]
```

- A dict is much more efficient for lookups
- The `.get()` function lets you specify a default value for if something isn't found.

Answer (score 2):

You can't inline "except"s like that; they only come in try/except pairs, and those can't be done in a lambda.

Unless this is a homework assignment or a puzzle, I'd use a dictionary instead:

```
>>> list_1 = ['a','b','c'] 
>>> list_2 = ['b','c']
>>> list_3 = [5,4]
>>> 
>>> mymap = dict(zip(list_2, list_3))
>>> list_4 = [mymap.get(x,0) for x in list_1]
>>> list_4
[0, 5, 4]
```

The zip combines the two lists into pairs:

```
>>> zip(list_2, list_3)
[('b', 5), ('c', 4)]
```

The dict makes a dictionary (an associative array) out of this:

```
>>> mymap = dict(zip(list_2, list_3))
>>> mymap
{'c': 4, 'b': 5}
>>> mymap['c']
4
>>> mymap['b']
5
```

and the `.get(a,b)` method on a dictionary means "look up key a and return that valu, but if the key's not found, return b."

```
>>> mymap.get("c", 0)
4
>>> mymap.get("nope", 0)
0
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what version of Python you're using, list.enumerate() might not be included yet.  enumerate would still exist as a builtin, and would return tuples of (index, item).  So the line you're looking for is:

```
list_4 = [(list_3[list_2.index(item)] if item in list_2 else 0) for index,item in enumerate(list_1)]
```

Comment: I wasn't trying to use the new feature, I just forgot the right function... :P Noticed when I tried to run it and failed, already updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: No problem :)  Long list comprehensions can get pretty finicky.  I wasn't sure if enumerate was a function of lists Python 3.